# android studio: attach source for debugging

Tags: android, debugging, jar

For andriod studio 2.2.3, how to attach source code for jars under app/libs/. I have searched a lot and read many posts in this site. None of them provide a working answer.

```
 app/libs
       a.jar
       b.jar
```

Any one know? Thanks.